# Why are helper methods not working in view specs?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec

I have a conditional in my view based upon a helper method defined in my application controller, which I defined as a helper method.

```
<% if logged_in? %>
```

When my spec hits this, it says:

```
ActionView::Template::Error:
   undefined method `logged_in?' for #<#<Class:0x007fdc06b71aa8>:0x007fdc0b9b0930>
```

When I use my browser, it works perfect. I tried stubbing it, but I get another error when I try to stub it on the view or controller. This is what my test looks like:

```
it "has a logout link" do
  render
  expect(rendered).to have_link "Logout"
end
```

Here's my gemfile:

```
ruby "2.4.1"

gem "bootsnap", ">= 1.1.0", require: false
gem "coffee-rails", "~> 4.2"
gem "jbuilder", "~> 2.5"
gem "pg"
gem "puma", "~> 3.11"
gem "rails", "~> 5.2.1"
gem "rails-controller-testing"
gem "sass-rails", "~> 5.0"
gem "turbolinks", "~> 5"
gem "uglifier", ">= 1.3.0"

group :development, :test do
  gem "byebug", platforms: %i[mri mingw x64_mingw]
end

group :development do
  gem "listen", ">= 3.0.5", "< 3.2"
  gem "spring"
  gem "spring-watcher-listen", "~> 2.0.0"
  gem "web-console", ">= 3.3.0"
end

group :test do
  gem "capybara", ">= 2.15"
  gem "chromedriver-helper"
  gem "factory_bot_rails"
  gem "rspec-rails", "~> 3.7"
  gem "selenium-webdriver"
  gem "shoulda-matchers", "~> 3.1"
end
```

Comment: But what's `render`?, clearly there's a mismatch in the object you're passing and `logged_in` is being invoked in.

Comment: I'm not passing an object. Render is a method from RSpec from my understanding. https://relishapp.com/rspec/rspec-rails/v/2-0/docs/view-specs/view-spec#passing-spec-with-explicit-template-rendering . And logged_in? is always supposed to be invoked. All it is, is session[:admin]. When I remove the conditional from my _navbar.html.erb file, then my view specs work, but then I can't test what the view should render when logged_in. I would expect that since my browser is working fine, that my specs should have access to the same helper methods that my views do...

Comment: Render is a "Rails" method, [see](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/fc5dd0b85189811062c85520fd70de8389b55aeb/actionview/lib/action_view/helpers/rendering_helper.rb#L27) the usage, that might be the problem.

Comment: I'm following exact examples listed on every guide I've found... Render isn't the issue here at all. Once I take `<% logged_in? %>` out of my view, my tests work fine.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

View specs usually does not need to call the real helper (if you wan't to test the helper then you can do a helper spec).

It's faster and easier to just stub the helper method to return the value you want for your given test:

```
context 'with a logged user' do
  before(:each) do
    allow(view).to receive(:logged_in?).and_return(true)
  end

  it 'has a logout link' do
    render
    expect(rendered).to have_link 'Logout'
  end
end

context 'with no logged user' do
  before(:each) do
    allow(view).to receive(:logged_in?).and_return(false)
  end

  it 'has a login link' do
    render
    expect(rendered).to have_link 'Login'
  end
end
```

When you do model, controller, views, helper or any other isolated test, it does not have access to all the app since it's designed to run fast. For example: controller tests does not render views by default, model specs only tests the model, view specs do not have a context of the request nor session, etc.

You can have full real user tests using integration (feature) specs which runs the whole user interaction from beginning to end with access to everything, even controlling what the user clicks.

Comment: So I've tried the before block and this error comes up:
`Failure/Error: allow(view).to receive(:logged_in?).and_return(true)
       #<#<Class:0x007fe0a0c0a160>:0x007fe0a5021cb8 @_routes=nil, @_config={} `

Comment: ..and the end part of the object is `does not implement: logged_in?`.

Comment: Where is you `logged_in?` helper defined? if it's on a helper file it should work https://relishapp.com/rspec/rspec-rails/docs/view-specs/view-spec#view-specs-can-stub-a-helper-method

Comment: My helper is defined on ApplicationController and defined as a helper by `helper_method :logged_in?`

Comment: Okay, wait a second... I just placed the method in `ApplicationHelper` and now it's working... Why is it not working in the spec when defined in `ApplicationController` and defined as a helper method? Do view specs not check `ApplicationController` for helper methods? **Thank you so much!**

Comment: I'm not sure what it does internally, but since a controller is not really needed for a view spec I guess it does not load them. Just guessing though.

Comment: I'm experiencing the same issue. Any way we can keep the helper methods in `ApplicaitonController` while having them available in view testing?

Answer (score 6):

Update to the accepted answer, it now seems necessary to use `without_partial_double_verification` to get around the `ActionView::Base does not implement: field_name` error.

Example code:

```
let(:logged_in) { true }

before(:each) do
  without_partial_double_verification do
    allow(view).to receive(:logged_in?).and_return(logged_in)
  end

  render
end

it 'has a logout link' do
  expect(rendered).to have_link 'Logout'
end

context 'with no logged user' do
  let(:logged_in) { false }

  it 'has a login link' do
    expect(rendered).to have_link 'Login'
  end
end
```